# Error when try to read datetime field in db2 by odbc with mono

Tags: c#, datetime, mono, db2, odbc

this is my problem. 
I have an application that need to work with different database. 
With mysql all works fine, with IBM db2 I have some problem. 
Details: 
I need to take data from a database IBM db2 using unixODBC and the ODBC driver "IBM i Access Client Solutions" (the last available from IBM). 
I have problem only if I read value from a timestamp field, and I don't have problem for all other types of data. 
The GetFieldType of the column that I want to read is System.DateTime,
but when I try to read this field with: 
reader.GetDateTime(1)   or   (DateTime) reader[1] 
(where reader is IDataReader object) 
the application return the follow error message:

```
  Unhandled Exception:
  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
  Parameter name: Parameters describe an unrepresentable DateTime.
  at System.DateTime..ctor (Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.DateTime..ctor (Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue (Int32 i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.get_Item (Int32 i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAP.OLAPprocessor.Run (IDbCommand OLAPSource, IDbCommand OLAPDest, DateTime TimeLimit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAP.OLAPprocessor.Run (IDbCommand OLAPSource, IDbCommand OLAPDest) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAPbuilder.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: Parameters describe an unrepresentable DateTime.
  at System.DateTime..ctor (Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, Int32 millisecond) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.DateTime..ctor (Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue (Int32 i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.get_Item (Int32 i) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAP.OLAPprocessor.Run (IDbCommand OLAPSource, IDbCommand OLAPDest, DateTime TimeLimit) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAP.OLAPprocessor.Run (IDbCommand OLAPSource, IDbCommand OLAPDest) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OLAPbuilder.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My Pc is a openSUSE 13.2 64bit, with mono 3.8.0, unixODBC 2.3.2, IBM i Access Client Solutions 1.1.0 

Thanks in advance to anyone will try to help me. 
Mirco

The source code:

```
IDbCommand DatabaseSource;

IDbConnection Connection;
Connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2};");

DatabaseSource = Connection.CreateCommand();
DatabaseSource.Connection = Connection;

DatabaseSource.CommandText = "select DTTMS  from TABTMS " +
                " where .........  " +  
                " order by DTTMS asc";  

IDataReader reader;

reader = DatabaseSource.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()==true)                  
{               
    DateTime tms = reader.GetDateTime(0);

    // ..... process this tms
}

reader.Close();
reader = null;
```

The error will happen when the application try to execute the row: 
DateTime tms = reader.GetDateTime(0);

Comment: Can we see the relevant C# code that throws this exception?

Comment: You may also want to check the actual timestamp value from the database.

Comment: I have  added the source code . Thanks !!!

Comment: Others info:         
   
- On the same machine, I can read the datetime fields via odbc using Apache/PHP without errors          

- If I run the same .exe in an other machine (openSuse 11.0 32bit), the application works fine without errors   
- The problem seem to be in the mono/odbc/IBM i Access Client system. Anyone have the same problem ?